# How to completely hide superclass method in Java

Tags: java

Recently I'm thinking about making my own Date library.
And I'm finding a problem here, here it is:

How do I hide a superclass method in subclass? So it won't be detected in subclass.

Example:
I have a class that extends to Date, and another class that extends to the previous class.
In my new subclass, it detects all the methods from Date, like getDate etc.
What I want is that in my subclass all the methods from Date are undetected, not throwing 
an exception, but completely undetected.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There is no way to do that... The only solution would be to have the method by the same name be `private` in the parent class, but then it means it is not callable from anywhere other than the parent class.

Comment: I have tried to override the getDate into private in my superclass, but it gives me an error, which I should change it to public.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

*Favour Composition over Inheritance here.*

Instead of inheriting a *Date* have it as a member field inside your *MyDate* class.

```
public class MyDate {
    private Date dt = new Date();

    // no getDate() available

    public long getTime() {
        return date.getTime();
    }
}
```

You get complete control over the Date API that's visible to your subclasses (without the need to throw any exceptions) but this approach is more practical when the methods you want to hide outnumber the ones you want to remain accessible.

Comment: Hmm, does Joda Date uses a pattern like this?
Because its return type is DateTime and not Date, although there's a method that is able to convert it into Date.

Comment: That's the beauty of it. You have complete control over the API. From method names to return types. You can choose to simplify and/or restrict the API as you want.

Comment: Ok I'm finding this is the closest answer to my problem, I'm trying to understand the logic.

By the way @Ravi -san, do you know why when i have this

`Date d=new Date();
System.out.println(d);`

It will produce an output like _Sat Jun 01 04:44:47 ICT 2013_.
But when I declare my own class object like

`MyClass mc=new MyClass();
System.out.println(mc);`

It produce an output like _MainPackage.MyClass@110b053_

How do I have an output like Date object when I output my class object?

Comment: This may give you complete control over the API, but you no longer have a subclass. A `Date` variable can't hold both a `HebrewDate` and `JapaneseDate` then.

Comment: override a toString() method and delegate to Date object

Comment: Nice, that's it.  
A closer step to my library making project hhehe.

Answer (score 11):

You can't hide it if it is extended, but you can override.

if you want your API user to not use the method I suggest a override and just throw this exception:

```
UnsupportedOperationException
```

but looking at what you wrote, you should consider making Date a field in your class, not extend the class.

Answer (score 7):

Not possible.

If what you want was possible, then inherintence would be broken. Suddenly, when you use a certain IS-A type of `Date`, you would not be able to call any `Date` type methods. This is wrong on several levels.  For example, it breaks the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Answer (score 5):

you can  use Delegation instead

```
public class NewDate{
  Date d;
  NewDate(){
     d = new Date();
  }

  methodsYouWantToChange(){
     // new implementation
  }


  methodsYouDontWantToChange(){
     d.methodsYouDontWantToChange();
  }


  newMethods(){
     // new implementation
  }
}
```

Comment: delegation can be a neat solution, lombok can also make it look clean:  http://projectlombok.org/features/Delegate.html

Comment: This delegation wouldn't allow my class having a return type of a Date, would it?

Comment: :/ I don't really understand what is this delegation for,
since it doesn't extends to Date class, I thought its return type wouldn't be Date.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern .. check this to know about delegation pattern

Answer (score 0):

Override the method and make it static, it will hide the method of super class